# Display array in Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Have problem to display an array in a Twig template.

In mysql I have a text field with value: 
**testtest-testtest2-testtest3**

In the controller I explode by '-' and pass it to Twig like so:

```
$ingred[] = explode('-', $ingreds);
$this->twig->render(['ingred' => $ingred]);
```

In the Twig template I loop through and it works:

```
   {% for ing in ingred %}
     <span class="ingridiantai">{{ ing.0 }}</span>
     <span class="ingridiantai">{{ ing.1 }}</span>
     <span class="ingridiantai">{{ ing.2 }}</span>
     <span class="ingridiantai">{{ ing.3 }}</span>
     <span class="ingridiantai">{{ ing.4 }}</span>
     <span class="ingridiantai">{{ ing.5 }}</span> 
   {% endfor %}
```

But what I want is to loop through all values without writing their key. Like this:

```
   {% for ing in ingred %}
     <span class="ingridiantai">{{ ing }}</span> 
   {% endfor %}
```

How can I do what? I was searching in the docs, but didn't find anything that would work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `[]` adds an element to an array and `explode` also creates an array. So now you have a 2-dimensional array.

Simply change the code in your controller to

```
$ingred = explode('-', $ingreds);
```